# Insert multiple document with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I made an API with express.js, and i use mongoDB for my database and mongoose as my ODM

I really confused when i want to insert multiple document to my collection in once post request.

Here my model :

```
const modul = require('../config/require');
const Schema = modul.mongoose.Schema;

let TeleponSchema = new Schema({
    _pelanggan : {type: String},
    telepon: {type: String, required: true}
});

module.exports = modul.mongoose.model('telepon', TeleponSchema, 'telepon');
```

and here my controller

```
const Telepon = require('../models/telepon.model')

exports.create = (req,res) => {
    let telepon = new Telepon({
        _pelanggan : req.body.pel,
        telepon: req.body.telepon
    });

    telepon.save((err,data) => {
        if(err){
            res.send({message:'eror', detail: err});
        }else{
            res.send({message:'success', data: data})
        }
    });

}
```

Then i post my request with postman like this :

[image]

but the result in my document is :
[image]

that's the problem, the value of 'telepon' is in the same row and separated by comma instead of insert a new row and create a new _id

i want the result of my collection like this :

(example)

[image]

Any help and suggestion would be much appreciated

Thank you!

Comment: Typically I make a controller and use express's router and export the router. if you do that you can use [insertMany()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insertMany/). You might be able to set it up the way you have it but I've never set it up this way.

Answer (score 0):

1) Per `.save` call you will only affect one document, check out `insertMany` to do multiple.

2) `req.body.telepon` is either an array of numbers, or is already just the comma delimited list of numbers; if it is an array the `.toString` will result in a comma delimited list anyways. So when you `new` up the Telepon it has both values in one property, which is what you see in the result.